# Invalid Json error during json object convert

Tags: c#

I am trying to convert a json response value to c# class value. But when i try to pass into `JsonDeserializer` that response it throwing error: Invalid Json. Bellow the code example is provided. Also note i am using RestSharp to make that url call. And the example url also provided bellow:

response url: `http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/items?apiKey=3zmwbajjf4ugzqhdtgsf59ac&upc=029986182548`

```
string url = "http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/items?apiKey=3zmwbajjf4ugzqhdtgsf59ac&upc=029986182548";
             var client = new RestClient(url);
             var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
             IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
             var deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
             var wmr = deserializer.Deserialize<WallMartData>(response);
```

Model class generated by http://json2csharp.com/

```
namespace WebApplication2.ViewModels
{
    public class Attributes
    {
        public string color { get; set; }
        public string productUrlText { get; set; }
        public string uniqueProductId { get; set; }
    }

    public class GiftOptions
    {
    }

    public class ImageEntity
    {
        public string thumbnailImage { get; set; }
        public string mediumImage { get; set; }
        public string largeImage { get; set; }
        public string entityType { get; set; }
    }

    public class WallMartData
    {
        public int itemId { get; set; }
        public int parentItemId { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public double msrp { get; set; }
        public double salePrice { get; set; }
        public string upc { get; set; }
        public string categoryPath { get; set; }
        public string shortDescription { get; set; }
        public string longDescription { get; set; }
        public string brandName { get; set; }
        public string thumbnailImage { get; set; }
        public string mediumImage { get; set; }
        public string largeImage { get; set; }
        public string productTrackingUrl { get; set; }
        public double standardShipRate { get; set; }
        public string color { get; set; }
        public bool marketplace { get; set; }
        public string modelNumber { get; set; }
        public string sellerInfo { get; set; }
        public string productUrl { get; set; }
        public string customerRating { get; set; }
        public int numReviews { get; set; }
        public string customerRatingImage { get; set; }
        public string categoryNode { get; set; }
        public string rhid { get; set; }
        public bool bundle { get; set; }
        public bool clearance { get; set; }
        public bool preOrder { get; set; }
        public string stock { get; set; }
        public Attributes attributes { get; set; }
        public string addToCartUrl { get; set; }
        public string affiliateAddToCartUrl { get; set; }
        public bool freeShippingOver35Dollars { get; set; }
        public GiftOptions giftOptions { get; set; }
        public List<ImageEntity> imageEntities { get; set; }
        public string offerType { get; set; }
        public bool availableOnline { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be because it's actually returning an array/list, have you tried `var wmr = deserializer.Deserialize<WallMartData[]>(response)`

Answer (score 1):

I've to guess, but the URL sends an array, not a single object of `WallMartData`.

Try something like this:

```cs
List<string> tmp = new List<string>();
using (var sr = new StreamReader("C:\\Temp\\tst.txt")) // tst.txt contains the url-response
{
    while(!sr.EndOfStream)
        tmp.Add(sr.ReadLine());
}

WallMartData[] x = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<WallMartData[]>(string.Join("\n", tmp));
```

In your case it would be:

```cs
string url = "http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/items?apiKey=3zmwbajjf4ugzqhdtgsf59ac&upc=029986182548";
             var client = new RestClient(url);
             var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
             IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
             var deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
             var wmr = deserializer.Deserialize<WallMartData[]>(response); // See the bracer here ;-)
```

Comment: I am not loading response from text. i am loading from url. Now can i implement it from url?

Comment: @NitikaPondith I wanted to provide a simple example without the webclient. I did add your snippet.

Answer (score 1):

The response sent is a json array so all you need to do is change the last line to:

```
var wmr = deserializer.Deserialize<List<WallMartData>>(response);
```

Basically deserialize into a list of your model.

Answer (score 0):

It return a List or Array

Try this

```cs
string url = "http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/items?apiKey=3zmwbajjf4ugzqhdtgsf59ac&upc=029986182548";
             var client = new RestClient(url);
             var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
             IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
             var deserializer = new JsonDeserializer();
             var wmr = deserializer.Deserialize<List<WallMartData>>(response);
```

Comment: This still says- {"Invalid JSON string"}